# Using methods as parameters in C# without delegates?

Tags: c#

I was going over some code that a knowledgeable colleague wrote and I came across a technique I found confusing.  Here is a snippet of code ...

```
public class TaxController : ApiController
{
    private StateTaxApi taxApi = new taxApi();

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<String>> GetStatesOwedTax(String taxId, String clientId)
    {
        try
        {
            return await taxApi.GetStatesOwedTax(clientId, GetTaxId(), GetClientId());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ApiException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not get tax states", e);
        }           
    }

    private String GetClientId()
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.Headers.GetValues("client-id").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            // TODO: Handle error here
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String GetTaxId()
    {
        return GetSessionValue("taxId") as String;
    }

    private Object GetSessionValue(String key)
    {
        var context = Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
        var session = context.Session;
        return session[key];
    }
}
```

Here you can see the methods are being passed as parameters to the method `GetStatesOwedTax()`:

```
return await taxApi.GetStatesOwedTax(clientId, GetTaxId(), GetClientId());
```

I thought the only way to do this was to use a delegate to represent the method being passed in as a parameter. I see no mention of  `Func(string)` defining the delegates. What am I missing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with delegates or `Func` or anything like that.  The answer is simple, the method(s) arent being passed, the _result_ of the method(s) are being passed.  Your coworker is just not assigning these to explicit variables and instead just passing the result straight into the next method.

Comment: Understood .. I have never seen this before. Is there a name defining what this practice is? Has it always been available or is it something new in C#? Or perhaps it has always been there and I was never aware of it.

Comment: @webworm It's pretty commonplace in most languages. I'm sure someone who is good with the historical context of programming, C# in particular, may be able to answer that, but I think it's a staple and has been around since the beginning.

Comment: This is just simple programming.  The methods return something, and you are passing the value they return to the method you are calling.  Its just the "order of operations", the methods are executed first then their returned value is passed to the "outer" method

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of this practice as it makes debugging more difficult and the compiler will optimize it the same either way. I'd assign the results to variables before passing to the function.

Comment: It's something that's in every language. It's just calling methods to retrieve their return values and then pass them as the parameter. It's not really any different than assigning the return value to a variable, other than that method being executed at a different time. The downside is as Michael said, you cannot Watch or debug that value.

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes; I added an upvote to compensate. My guess is that some people see this question as "too simple". This is a very basic syntax that most programmers learn within the first weeks/months of writing their first line of code, and it's been ubiquitous in almost any programming language ever since the function was invented. I guess they forget that even _they_ didn't know of it before some point. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method isn't being passed, the result of the method is being passed. As simple as that is to say, I find an example always serves better.

```
public void Start()
{
    var result = DoMath(GetX(), GetY());
}

public int GetX()
{
    return 1;
}

public int GetY()
{
    return 2;
}

public int DoMath(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

As you can see in the example, `DoMath()` needs two ints passed into it. In lieu of

```
public void Start()
{
    var x = GetX();
    var y = GetY();
    var result = DoMath(x, y);
}
```

you can do the method calls directly in the parameters of the `DoMath()` method.

Now, whether this is simpler, better, good/bad practice all comes down to personal style and overall complexity. If it's very readable then you can save space by doing this, but it does risk muddying up the waters and not being as apparent to what you're doing. So I can't say if you should or should not do it, just saying that you can do it.

As mentioned by Vilx in the comments, an easy way to tell if the method is being passed vs the results of the method are the inclusion of the parenthesis. If they are there (as they are in this case) then it means the method will be evaluated and its result used.

Comment: Ahh, beat me to it. :)

Comment: Oh, also should add - note the parenthesis after `GetX()` and `GetY()` - that means the function will be called and the results used. If instead you said `DoMath(GetX, GetY)` - **then** you're passing the functions themselves with all the delegates and stuff.